# ImagExpress Version 8 on 64 bit

Tags: .net

I am trying to find 64 bit version of Pegasus ImagExpress. The one they have for download is v10 and they have changed the library signatures and the usage. We are compelled to change the code base now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been noted that there is no 64 bit version of Version 8 ImagExpress. We need to download and use Version 10, and make necessary changes.